lettucemod doesn't allow to do wildcard pattern searches
I am using lettucemod version 3.8.1 and it looks like it doesn't allow to do wildcard pattern matches.
According to https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/query_syntax/:

"In DIALECT 2 or greater, wildcard pattern matches are expressed as "w'foo*bar?'".
Note the use of double quotes to contain the w pattern."

Double quotes are required to make it work but when I have a multifield query like:

"@field1: w'fulltext*0c2d07f6afc149b388e6a84bba808ca6' @tagField:
{tagvalue } "

the query doesn't work using lettucemod.
How double quotes should be used?
How should I construct string with the query so ft.search/ft.aggregate use it correctly using lettuce-mod??

Please format your question correctly, It's very hard to read.
